# Recalculate Offset Value on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

I am creating a continuous looping page of images. Looping in both directions from div #loop-end to #loop-start with jquery scroll and offset top.

https://codepen.io/akmalmo/pen/eYgoQKd

```
var element_position = $('#loop-start').offset().top;

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = element_position;

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test + 2) {


 var loopend = $('#loop-end').offset().top;
 var loopstart = $('#loop-start').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(document).scrollTop() >= loopend + 1 ) {
    $(document).scrollTop($('#loop-start').offset().top)
    }
  else if ( $(document).scrollTop() <= loopstart - 1 ) {
    $(document).scrollTop($('#loop-end').offset().top)
    }
    
});
         }
});
```

The problem is that this function breaks on window resize and I am wondering if there is a simple way to recalculate the offset value? Or preferably having it calculate the offset in a more responsive fashion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) to recalculate the looping variables each time the window is resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // your function
});
```

Comment: Right. But so, would I do a duplicate of the variables inside that event? I’ve tried that, and it makes it work for the forward looping... but it breaks the backwards loop. What is best practice? It also feels really sluggish when I resize the window and that is because the event sort of firing each moved px? Could one throw in a delay of some sort?